# override search form EasyAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony2-easyadmin

how to override search form for an entity in EasyAdminBundle? and the right way to override search action for this entity?
thank's

Comment: Hi, Please give a little more information about what `EasyAdminBundle` is and how you're trying to use it. Any code examples or references you can provide will help people answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

A proper way how to override search (and any) action in EasyAdminBundle is described [in the official documentation](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/book/7-complex-dynamic-backends.md).

In most cases, you probably won't need to override the whole search action. Maybe you just need to **adjust the query builder criterias so it returns different results or filters it out**. You can use [Doctrine Criterias](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) to do that.

I wrote [a detailed tutorial](http://blog.ikvasnica.com/entry/easy-admin-bundle-how-to-remove-null-values-when-sorting-entities) how to filter out, for example, null values from a search result set in EasyAdminBundle. You can use it to change any search query in any way accordingly.